# Bootstrap 4 with Sass in DXA 2.0 CTP 2?

Tags: dxa

Currently DXA is using Bootstrap 3 with LESS. Is there any way to use Bootstrap 4 with SASS in DXA 2.0 CTP 2 website project?

We will be using the CTP 2 unless CTP 3 is released in the next 2 weeks or so. But eventually we would like to keep as up to date with the CTP releases and the final release as possible.

Please let us know if it is possible to use Bootstrap 4 and SASS with the available CTP releases and also if there is any plan on including this in the final DXA 2.0 release.

Many thanks

Comment: Since you mention DXA 2.0 (which isn't released yet), can you **edit** your question and elaborate on if you are talking about wanting to change this on one of the CTP releases, or whether you are wondering if that will be included in the DXA 2.0 release?

Comment: We will be using the CTP 2 unless CTP 3 is released in the next 2 weeks or so. But eventually we would like to keep as up to date with the CTP releases and the final release as possible.

Comment: Any answers to this pretty old question.  Going to clients and telling them we’ve to customise a chunk of DXA to support a modern stack is a hard sell for DXA.